# AsyncTask to call another function within class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Basically, do I have to put code I want to run on another thread inside doInBackground, or can I call another function/class/whatever-it-is-functions-are-called-in-JAVA within doInBackground and have it run asynchronously? IE: (example code I found online)

```
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        txt.setText("Executed");
        return null;
  }
```

is how I have seen it done, but can I instead do:

```
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           postToServer(x,y,z,h);
      }
```

and have it call a function I already wrote and then have that function run in another thread? Sometimes my HTTP server is a bit slow to respond (it is but a lowly testing server at the moment) and Android automatically pops up the kill process box if my postToServer() call takes more than 5 seconds, and also disables my UI until the postToServer() call finishes. This is a problem because I am developing a GPS tracking app (internally for the company I work for) and the UI option to shut the tracking off freezes until my postToServer() finishes, which sometimes doesn't ever happen. I apologize if this has been answered, I tried searching but haven't found any examples that work the way I'm hoping to make this work.

Comment: A method is always executed in the thread of the caller. Direct calls can't switch a thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but you will have to move the UI updates to `onPostExecute` as it is run on the UI thread.

```
public MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<foo, bar, baz> {

    ...

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       postToServer(x,y,z,h);
    }  

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        txt.setText("Executed");
    }

    ....

}
```

You may want to pass in the TextView to the constructor of the `AsyncTask` and store it as a WeakReference.
    private final WeakReference textViewReference;

```
public MyAsyncTask(TextView txt) {
    textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(txt);
}
```

And then in onPostExecute you would make sure that the TextView reference still exists.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    TextView txt = textViewReference.get();
    if (txt != null)
        txt.setText("Executed");
}
```

If you want to notify the user that the task is executing I would put that before invoking the `AsyncTask`.

```
 myTextView.setText("Update in progress...");
 new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

then in `onPostExecute` set the `TextView` to say "Update complete."

Comment: Okay, and if I don't really need to update the UI should I still be doing it this way or is there a different way to force it into a background thread if I don't need to return info from it? Eventually I need to cache the data if my HTTP request doesn't go through (ie: lack of network) but that I can do from within my postToServer() and keep it all off of the main thread (I think, this is totally new ground for me).

Comment: You could use a `Thread` or a `Runnable` with a `Handler`, but I would stick with `AsyncTask` as it is the most widely used and if you decide you want to show progress or update the UI at a later date it will require less rework.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. One more question if you don't mind: how can I make x,y,z, and h visible if I put this inside of another method (onLocationChanged in this instance, which trips whenever the GPS location changes)? Eclipse tells me the only way I can do it is to declare the variables final, but if I do that won't it stop me from updating them again if the location changes?

Comment: Sorry, I guess declaring it final it still seems to work for me. I'm guessing this is because these variables are created and destroyed every time the location changes so they are only "Final" for the time it takes for the code to execute. I can see in LogCat that these tasks and my main thread have different TID numbers, which I'm guessing is Thread ID.

Comment: You could pass in the values for x, y, z, h as the params in `doInBackground`.  You could pass them in as the `String` array, or if you wanted to use an object you could define the `AsyncTask` like `AsyncTask<SomeClass, Void, WhateverYouWantPassedToOnPostExecute>` and then `doInBackground` will become `doInBackground(SomeClass... params)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it the second way?

From what you've posted it seems like it should work fine how you have it in the second example.

However (perhaps unrelated to your question?) in your first example I think it will fail because you are trying to change the UI from a background thread. You'd want to put the parts that manipulate the TextView inside of `onPostExecute()` rather than `doInBackground()`

Comment: Thank you, that code was merely copy and pasted from a different post I was reading about asynctask so I haven't the slightest idea if it will compile or not. Just wanted to show an example of what I had been seeing in my research today. Thus far I have not tried it, and unfortunately am leaving work right now so I won't be able to until tomorrow, just wanted to test the waters and see what you professionals thought. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the call to your `postToServer` method (that's the name in java) will run off the main thread. 
Everything inside the `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask` is run on a pooled thread, but be sure to NOT invoke it directly! Call `execute` on your asynktask instead, the android framework will do the work for you and run `doInBackground` on another thread.

try doing something like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    // this runs on another thread
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // assuming x, y, z, h are visible here
        postToServer(x, y, z, h);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    // this runs on main thread
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        txt.setText("Executed");
    }

}.execute(); // call execute, NOT doInBackGround
```

Also, notice that every other method of `AsyncTask`, such as `onPostExecute` runs on the main thread, so avoid heavy loading them.

Comment: Thank you (repeats in head: method, method, method) very much. I'm kind of confused by what you are saying, so let me see if I can clear this up in my noob head a bit. If I call the method from doInBackground will the HTTP request that is in postToServer be running in the main thread, or in the separate pooled AsyncTask thread? IE: in the most basic terms, will my UI still freeze up if my server doesn't respond very quickly?

Comment: I added a code example, if you follow it your ui will not freeze

Answer (score -1):

Basically The Bottom Line Is the doInBackground() method is Can't interact with The Ui Thread Or The Main thread. that's Why When You are Try To Interact With The TextView in doInBackground () it Will Crash the UI Thread Cuz It's Illegal.
so if anytime You want to Interact with the UI Thread,When You are Working on doInBackground You need to Override
   OnPostExecute() //this Function is Called when The doInBackground Function job is Done. 
So You can Update The UI Thread Content By this When You're Job is Done In doInBackground () or You are In doInBackground ()